# Repeating code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie at JS and jQuery and I don't like to rewrite code or functions over and over again. Here's my code:

```
var validarN= function(){
    $("#username").blur(function(){
        var valor= $(this).val();
        var regex= /^[\w]{4,12}$/;
        if (valor.match(regex)) {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");;
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success"); 
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        };


    });
};

var validarPw = function(){
    $("#pass").blur(function(){
        var varlor, regex
        valor= $(this).val()
        regex= /(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{6,}$/;
        if (valor.match(regex)) {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        };
    });
};
var confirmarPw= function() {
    $("#passV").blur(function() {
        var valor= $(this).val();
        var valorP= $("#pass").val();
        regex= /(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{6,}$/;
        if (valor.match(regex) && valor==valorP) {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        };
    });
}
```

I'm doing a form validation. I would like a form to encapsulate the jQuery functions and the blur event, too, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can support what ikryvorotenko says, but in case you want to continue with your own function you could do

```
var validate = function(sel,regex){
    $(sel).blur(function(){
        var varlor $(this).val()
        if (valor.match(regex)) {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        };
    });
};
```

and then

```
var validarN=function(){validate("#username",/^[\w]{4,12}$/);},
    validarPw=function(){validate("#pass",/(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{6,}$/);},
    confirmarPw=function(){validate("#passV",/(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{6,}$/);};
```

Comment: yeah i think in that way too, i found a validator jquery with bootstrap, but as im new at js, i was thinking that is better for me to learn by coding this by my self

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to avoid extra code is reusing what is already created and tested for some time. Take a look at jQuery validation plugin which provides lots of default validation methods and well customisable itself - http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Jquery validation plugin for doing form validations.
As far as your code goes, you can do some thing like this..

```
    var validarN= function(){
        $("#username").blur(function(){
            var regex= /^[\w]{4,12}$/;
            processRequest(this,regex);
     });
    };

   function processRequest(ctrl, regex){
           var valor= $(ctrl).val(); 
           var formGroup =  $(ctrl).closest(".form-group");
            if (valor.match(regex)) {
                $(formGroup).removeClass("has-error");
                $(formGroup).addClass("has-success"); 
            } else {
                $(formGroup).addClass("has-error");
            };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where ever there is repeating code, create a named functions which take arguments. Then call the function passing the data. Something along the lines of:

```
function validateField(field, regex) {
  if (field.match(regex)) {
        $(field).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");;
        $(field).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success"); 
    } else {
        $(field).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    };
}

var validarN = function(){
  var valor= $(this).val();
  var regex= /^[\w]{4,12}$/;
  validateField(field, regex);
});
```

};